# XSLT transformation(xml to xml)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like this:

```
<object>
    <string name "order">1<string>
    <string name "item">1<string>
</object>
<object>
    <string name "order">1<string>
    <string name "item">2<string>
</object>
<object>
    <string name "order">2<string>
    <string name "item">1<string>
</object>
```

I want to transform the xml to this strukture:

```
<object order=1>
    <string name "item">1<string>
    <string name "item">2<string>
</object>
<object order=2>
    <string name "item">1<string>
</object>
```

I want to transform the input XML dynamically with XSLT but i have trouble doing it.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to bring your source XML to a proper form.

1. XML document contains **only one** root tag (let's call it *main*)
   and this tag can contain multiple source tags (e.g. *object*).
2. Each tag (as you wrote in *string* tags) can contain an *attribute* with a *value*
   (in your case *name* and *order*), but between them must be "=" sign.
3. In the case of *object* tag you remembered to put a "/" in the closing tag,
   but you forgot about it in each closing *string* tag.

So the proper input XML (after required corrections) is:

```
<main>
  <object>
    <string name="order">1</string>
    <string name="item">1</string>
  </object>
  <object>
    <string name="order">1</string>
    <string name="item">2</string>
  </object>
  <object>
    <string name="order">2</string>
    <string name="item">1</string>
  </object>
</main>
```

Now let's get down to the main business.
In the description I put row numbers - references to the final solution.

We start with *xsl:output indent="yes"* (row 2), otherwise all content
would be in a single row (difficult to read).

The XML code contains a single *tempate* matching *main* tag (row 4).

The first thing it does is to *copy* (opening and closing *main* tags - row 5).

Then, row 6 contains the grouping loop (*for-each-group*). The objects groupped are *object* elements (see *select* clause) and the grouping key is the content of *string* child tag (relative to the current *object*) with attribute *name* equal to "order" (see *group-by* clause).

So the first group contains *object* tags No 1 and 2 (they both have
*string name="order"* tag with content of "1" and the second group contains
*object* tag No 3.

Then (for each group of source *object* tags) we create an output *object* element (row 7).

This element must have an attribute named *order* with the value of the
current grouping key (row 8).

The current element (output *object*) is to contain data from each element in
the current group, so we have to write *for-each* statement, looping through
all source *object* tags - the content of the current group (see *select* clause, row 9).

Within this loop, for each input *object*, we crete a *string* element (row 10).

This element is to have an attribute named "name" (see *name* clause) and
its value should be "item" (see *select* clause) - row 11.

The last thing to do is to create the content of the output tag - the
value of child *string* tag (relative to the current *object*) with
*name* attribute of *item* value - row 12.

All further rows in XSL are closing tags.

Below you have a complete XSL solution.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="main">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="object" group-by="string[@name='order']">
        <xsl:element name="object">
          <xsl:attribute name="order" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:element name="string">
              <xsl:attribute name="name" select="'item'"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="string[@name='item']"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```